# Arduino Script: $1 only works if pwd = `~` but not anywhere else

Tags: java, bash, shell

I have the following script, `arduino`,

```
#!/bin/sh

APPDIR="$(dirname -- "$(readlink -f -- "${0}")" )"

cd "$APPDIR"

for LIB in \
    java/lib/rt.jar \
    java/lib/tools.jar \
    lib/*.jar \
    ;
do
    CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:${LIB}"
done
export CLASSPATH

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export PATH="${APPDIR}/java/bin:${PATH}"

java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel processing.app.Base $1
```

If pwd is `~`,

```
vng:/home/vng () $ arduino ~/Desktop/EZ_com/EZ_com.ino
```

this works

However, if I change my directory to anywhere else:

```
vng:/home/vng () $ cd ~/Desktop/EZ_com/
vng:/home/vng/Desktop/EZ_com () $ ls
EZ_com.ino
vng:/home/vng/Desktop/EZ_com () $ arduino EZ_com.ino
```

This results in the arduino IDE opening an empty file.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

The jar library path you are appending in classpath seems relative to home dir. Try making it absolute.

Comment: I tried adding ``pwd`/` in front of $1 and it didn't make it absolute. Any ideas?

Comment: I am talking about jars listed in for loop. e.g. java/lib/rt.jar. You should try using absolute path eg /home/vng/java/lib/rt.jar